# brew and mysql55 fails to install

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I have to install mysql 5.5 on my machine, but I also need mysql 5.6 sometimes for other projects. I installed mysql 5.6 through brew, and thought, that it would be easy, to just switch between them with `brew switch mysql 5.5`.

Unfortunately, when trying to install 5.5, I get the following error and can't find anything on google or other sites:

```
$ brew install mysql55
==> Downloading http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/mysql-5.5/mysql-5.5.30.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql55-5.5.30.tar.gz
==> cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.30 -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/var/mysql55 -DINSTALL_MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.30/share/man -DINSTALL_DO
==> make
ld: can't write to output file: resolveip, errno=28 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [extra/resolveip] Error 1
make[1]: *** [extra/CMakeFiles/resolveip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself:

- Deinstalling mysql AND mysql55
- Running `brew doctor` and fix all issues
- Install again

I can't tell exactly what it was, but now it seems to work.

Comment: Were you able to `brew switch` after this? I get `Error: mysql not found in the Cellar`. (I never installed `mysql`, just `mysql55`.)